# Can anyone explain what these GParted partitions are?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk, resize, disk-management

[image: GParted screenshot]

I just want to know if `/dev/sda3` is unallocated space or if it's some encrypted Windows data. I'm dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu right now, but my Ubuntu partition only has a measly 21 GiB.

I want to shrink the `/dev/sda3` partition and expand my Ubuntu partition, but before I do, I want to make sure I know exactly what that `/dev/sda3` partition contains.

Comment: Do not know bitlocker, but that is an encrypted Windows. Your standard Windows UEFI/gpt partitions. About half way down in this is Layout. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations Vendors may then add additional vendor recovery partitions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I'm pretty new to using StackExchange, and I was wondering if you could explain the convention for making a comment versus creating an answer?

Comment: Comments are supposed to be asking for more info or further discussion. Answers are where then the question can be resolved and if accepted other users can find the answer. Many post answers and let user select. I often just post a comment and if that seems to be correct may convert to answer. Users can also answer own question with more detail but cannot immediately accept. I tend to prefer forum's where you have more discussion and space to comment.